# Catching ClassCastException in a generic method when doing generic cast

Tags: java, generics, casting, classcastexception, type-erasure

Suppose I have a method

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T extends Number> T getNumber() {
   try {
      return (T)number; 
   } catch (ClassCastException e) {
      return null;
   }
}
```

Assuming `number` is an instance of `Integer`, invoking method like

```
Float f = getNumber();
```

results into a `ClassCastException`.

I know (somehow) that this is because of **type erasure** but could someone provide more profound explanation why the exception escalates up to the assignment level and is not catchable inside method?

**NOTE:** I do have the version `public <T extends Number> T getNumber(Class<T> classT)` that checks the type from classT but was hoping to get rid of passing the `classT` and stopped wondering the above problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After type erasure, `return (T)number` becomes `return (Number)number` (since `Number` is the type bound of `T`), which doesn't throw an exception (since `number` is an instance of `Integer`).

On the other hand, the assignment

```
Float f = getNumber();
```

is compiled to

```
Float f = (Float) getNumber();
```

since `getNumber()` returns a `Number`, which can't be assigned to a `Float` variable without a cast.

This cast throws the `ClassCastException` when `getNumber()` is not a `Float`.

> [4.6. Type Erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.6)
>
> Type erasure is a mapping from types (possibly including parameterized types and type variables) to types (that are never parameterized types or type variables). We write |T| for the erasure of type T. The erasure mapping is defined as follows...
>
> The erasure of a type variable (§4.4) is the erasure of its leftmost bound.

Comment: Thanks for the clear, understandable answer (how can you write so fast & clear, I envy...). I assume if I dropped the ` extends Number` so `<T>` only it would be `return (Object)number`?