# How to use @SuppressWarning("unchecked") to specific lines of code and not into method level

Tags: java

I have a function created where i have used @SuppressWarning("unchecked")  at method level and it works as expected but i need to move this @SuppressWarning("unchecked") to only those lines of code where the warning is coming in and not at method level:

```
public static <T> T marshal(Class<T> cls , String xml){
      T res;
      if(cls == xml.getClass()){
          res=(T) xml;--->Need to use @SuppressWarning("unchecked") before this line
      }else{
         JAXBContext ct= JAXBContext.newInstance(cls);
         Unmarshal marshal=ctx.createUnmarshller();
         res=(T)marshal.unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));-->Need to use @SuppressWarning("unchecked") before this line
      }
      return res;
     }
```

In the above function I have to use @SuppressWarning("unchecked") after if and else because these are the places where warnings are shown.

Comment: Simply put `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") final T uncheckedXml = (T) xml;` right before the assignment of `res = uncheckedXml;` for the "true" case, and similar for the second "else" one.

Comment: Related (but specific to IntelliJ): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798908/disable-warning-in-intellij-for-one-line

Answer (score 0):

Java annotations can only be placed at certain constructs, which are enumerated in [`ElementType`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/annotation/ElementType.html), which is used when specifying where an annotation can be used (in `@Target()`). [`SuppressWarnings`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) specifically is declared with:

> ```
> @Target({TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE,MODULE})
> @Retention(SOURCE)
> public @interface SuppressWarnings
> ```

Which means it can be placed on one of these declaration contexts. So as @fluffy proposed [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343284/how-to-use-suppresswarningunchecked-to-specific-lines-of-code-and-not-into/65343835#comment115520653_65343284), one way to introduce such a context the annotation can be placed at is to introduce a local variable:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") 
final T uncheckedXml = (T) xml;

res = uncheckedXml;
```

Comment: I can't edit your answer because of the "min-6 characters to change" rule, but casting to `T` in the `res = (T) uncheckedXml` is redundant and may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a generic method to handle `@SuppressWarning("unchecked")` when appropriate, so defined like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <C> C cast(Object o) {
    return (C) o;
}
```

However, when you use it and want to have checks you need to check for possible `ClassCastException` upon assignment ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47548573/6413377)). So like:

```
try {
    res = cast(xml);
} catch (ClassCastException cce) {
    // a bug, help!
}
```